# Не могу правильно настроить ssl сертификат на сайте

Tags: wordpress, ubuntu, ssl, https

Купила ссл сертификат, сайт стоит на удаленном VPS на Ubuntu 16. Залила сертификат в /etc/ssl, в итоге главная страница работает, а ссылки не работают вообще, выходит 404 ошибка, страницы даже через меню не открываются. Перерыла весь интернет, всяко разно меняла .htaccess

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

и так

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} =off 
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [QSA,L]
```

и так

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} !^443$
RewriteRule .* https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]
```

и так

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} !https
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

все безрезультатно.

Сайт работает на worpress при попытке добавить новую запись выходит ошибка: *Ошибка публикации. Ответ не является допустимым ответом JSON.* Все ссылки изменены на https как в БД так и home и site url через общие настройки.
Меняла настройки apache прописывала отдельно 443 порт в конфиге:
'''

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
        # The ServerName directive sets the request scheme, hostname and port that
        # the server uses to identify itself. This is used when creating
        # redirection URLs. In the context of virtual hosts, the ServerName
        # specifies what hostname must appear in the request's Host: header to
        # match this virtual host. For the default virtual host (this file) this
        # value is not decisive as it is used as a last resort host regardless.
        # However, you must set it for any further virtual host explicitly.
        #ServerName www.mydomain.ru
        ServerAdmin sunS4@mail.ru
        DocumentRoot /var/www/mysite.ru/public_html
        # Available loglevels: trace8, ..., trace1, debug, info, notice, warn,
        # error, crit, alert, emerg.
        # It is also possible to configure the loglevel for particular
        # modules, e.g.
        #LogLevel info ssl:warn
        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/mysite.ru-error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/mysite.ru-access.log combined

        # For most configuration files from conf-available/, which are
        # enabled or disabled at a global level, it is possible to
        # include a line for only one particular virtual host. For example the
        # following line enables the CGI configuration for this host only
        # after it has been globally disabled with "a2disconf".
        #Include conf-available/serve-cgi-bin.conf
        SSLEngine on
        SSLCertificateFile /etc/ssl/certs/mysite.ru.crt
        SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/ssl/certs/mysite.ru.crt
        SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/ssl/private/mysite.ru.key

</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
        # The ServerName directive sets the request scheme, hostname and port that
        # the server uses to identify itself. This is used when creating
        # redirection URLs. In the context of virtual hosts, the ServerName
        # specifies what hostname must appear in the request's Host: header to
        # match this virtual host. For the default virtual host (this file) this
        # value is not decisive as it is used as a last resort host regardless.
        # However, you must set it for any further virtual host explicitly.
        ServerName mysite.ru
        ServerAlias www.mysite.ru

        ServerAdmin sunS4@mail.ru
        DocumentRoot /var/www/mysite.ru/public_html

        # Available loglevels: trace8, ..., trace1, debug, info, notice, warn,
        # error, crit, alert, emerg.
        # It is also possible to configure the loglevel for particular
        # modules, e.g.
        #LogLevel info ssl:warn

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/mysite.ru-error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/mysite.ru-access.log combined

        # For most configuration files from conf-available/, which are
        # enabled or disabled at a global level, it is possible to
        # include a line for only one particular virtual host. For example the
        # following line enables the CGI configuration for this host only
        # after it has been globally disabled with "a2disconf".
        #Include conf-available/serve-cgi-bin.conf
        ProxyPassMatch ^/(.*\.php(/.*)?)$ unix:/run/php/php7.1-fpm.sock|fcgi://localhost/var/www/mysite.ru.ru/public_html
        <IfModule mod_header.c>
                Header always append X-Frame-Options SAMEORIGIN
                Header set X-Content-Type-Options nosniff
                Header set X-XSS-Protection "1; mode=block"
        </IfModule>
'''
```

Подскажите пожалуйста что я делаю не так? И куда надо копать?

Comment: В каждой системе, после установки ssl должен появляться файл навроде default-ssl.conf с основными настройками. Этот файл в зависимости от платформы может находиться в разных местах. но в папке /etc. У вас такой имеется? В нём должны быть настройки про протокол ssl и пути к сертификатам.

Comment: Да есть такой. На первый взгляд вроде все в нем правильно.

Comment: SSLCertificateFile      /etc/ssl/certs/mysite.ru.crt
SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/ssl/private/mysite.ru.key

Comment: Установите nginx и используйте его как прокси для апача, там легче и сертификат настроить и производительность вырастит если правильно настроите статику. Примеров настройки очень много. Так же, вы должны быть уверены что ваш сертификат валидный и вы не тестите на локал хосте :D

Comment: Санса, вы показали пути к файлам сертификата, именно они прописаны в конфигурационном файле ssl? Как сказал Вадим, если сертификат выдан для реального домена, то его настраивать и проверять на домашнем сервере не получится.

Comment: Да конечно там реальный домен прописан. Я уже нечаянно грохнула и восстановила БД :ь И все ссылки все ровно 404 Not Found
The requested URL was not found on this server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Разобралась! Надо в конфиге apache2.conf в разделе для var/www/ поменять с AllowOverride None на AllowOverride All. И тогда уже начинает работать htaccess. После обязательно перезагрузите апач service apache2 restart

Answer (score 0):

Не надо творческих метаний. Стоит заглянуть в документацию.

[htaccess в WordPress](https://wordpress.org/support/article/htaccess/)

[HTTPS for WordPress](https://wordpress.org/support/article/https-for-wordpress/)

Там все настройки прописаны.